# Pie chart displays incorrect percentage

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie, percentage

Pie charts in my document are displaying incorrect percentage with following code.  Min value is 0 and max value is 104. For example, out of 104, correct answers are 42.3%, 29.8% and 26.9%, but values displayed on the chart are 44%, 31%, and 29% shown in the chart.  please address this issue

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{centering}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.7]
\pie[text = legend] {
44/ A,
31/ B,
29/ C}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Strategies }
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig:SQ12}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: As an aside, speaking as a statistician, you shouldn't be using pie charts anyway.  See my paper [Graphics for Univariate Data Pie is Delicious but not Nutritious](http://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/graphics-for-univariate-data-pie-is-delicious-but-not-nutritious/)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I quickly read your paper, its good read. but my data is not much, just 4 to 5 slice, which is perfectly fine ( I think) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** the code in this answer does *not* work after the package was rewritten for version 0.4 (I think) in 2020. Hence, if you have a somewhat recent installation, this isn't going to work.

---

Your current pie is actually wrong, as `pgf-pie` by default assumes that the values will add to 100. Try for example `\tikz{\pie{44/ A,31/ B,129/ C}}` for an extreme case.

If the values do not add up to 100, you need the `sum=auto` option to `\pie`.

That doesn't quite do what you want though, as the package will print the values, not the percentages. Hence, some modification is needed, which you can do with `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`. This lets you modify a macro by replacing a specific piece of code with something else.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}
% replace the following
{\path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) node
    {\scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}};
    }
% with this:
    {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfpie@sum}{100}}{
      % \equal is a string comparison, so it will only be true if sum=auto is not in effect
      % (even if the values add up to 100, \pgfpie@sum becomes 100.0, which as a string is not the same as 100
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{#3}
    }{
      % so if sum=auto is in effect, calculate the percentage
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{#3/\pgfpie@sum*100}
      }
    
    % the modification here is from \pgfpie@numbertext{#3}. 
    \path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) node
    {\scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\tmp}}};    }
    {}
    {}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.7]
% you need after number=\% because that gets turned off with sum=auto
\pie[text = legend, sum=auto, after number=\%] {
44/ A,
31/ B,
29/ C}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This does the job almost correctly. However, if a value is 0, your code still writes the node 0% there. For instance, with this line of code `\pie[text=legend, sum=auto, after number=\%] {2/Very dissatisfied,0/Dissatisfied,8/Neutral,10/Satisfied,3/Very satisfied}`. Please help.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul This doesn't do the job at all it seems, it simply doesn't work with latest version of the package. I'll see if I can make it work again, perhaps later today. (That said, the question doesn't say anything about special handling of zero, so I think it *did* work correctly :) If you want special handling of zero -- not printing it I suppose -- that is actually a slightly different question, or an extension of the one above. Nitpicking aside though, I'll have a look later.)

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Looking at the code, I realize I'll not be able to make this work with the latest version of the package. Someone might be able to, so you could consider posting a new question. So sorry, but I won't be able to help.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Of course, you can simply compute the percentages outside LaTeX and use those values in the pie.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, calculating the values outside is always an option. But I have quite many of them, and need to meet a deadline!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, you told it to put the numbers you got.  Why not put 42.3, 29.8 and 26.9?

Either that, or divide each of what you have now by 104, which I think will work in the code (although I didn't try).

Comment: Thanks, I already tried your method, and it is "almost" working fine, but I was looking for proper method that can compute the exact value, and I should not use the calculator for other pie charts :-)